# Convert Windows Disk Path to Uri Path in Registry File

Tags: windows, path, windows-10, registry, uri

As I mentioned in the question already, I am trying to convert the Windows path to Uri Path inside registry file.

Then copy the converted Uri path to Clipboard, as intended in the code below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy As Uri Info]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy As Uri Info\command]
@="cmd.exe /q /v:on /e:on /c \"set FilePath=\"%1\" & set UriPath=file:///%%FilePath:\=/%% & echo !UriPath!|clip\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Copy As Uri Info]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Copy As Uri Info\command]
@="cmd.exe /q /v:on /e:on /c \"set FilePath=\"%1\" & set UriPath=file:///%%FilePath:\=/%% & echo !UriPath!|clip\""
```

But when I run this registry file and then, right-click and select "Copy As Uri Info" on any file or folder, it copies "!UriPath!" into clipboard.

Can anyone help out ?